# How to run code GUI inside a Docker container on a remote server?

Tags: docker, x11, remote-server

I have created a Docker container on a Linux server. I connected to this container from my laptop using VSCode and can run some code. However, I'm unable to run certain programs that require GUI, such as gedit. How can I configure it to run GUI-based applications from the container on my local machine?

I know that I can achieve this by X11, but I don't know how to configure it.

Comment: You can mount the X11 port (which is what you'd do if you were running the container locally), but the X server may not even be running.  I'm not sure whether VSCode has the ability to forward remotely anyways.  That's before you get into whether your container and host have the proper setup to provide the necessary libraries/drivers.  Is there a specific reason you want to run a GUI program?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I train models using some game environments from the gymnasium, and I need to see the performance of the models I obtained. So I need to render the games.

Comment: That's not a "display in VSCode remotely" problem, though.  If you're _just_ trying to render in a docker container, there are existing questions/answers for that (although depending on the game engine, you may not need to map in the X11 port).  If you're evaluating output, you may not need to do this remotely (display model behavior locally).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: On the linux server, I run `xhost +`, and `echo $DISPLAY`, to see the avaliable DISPLAY port. Then I build a container with the following command

```bash
docker run -id --name your_env --net=host -e DISPLAY=:15.0 -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all -e NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all -v /home/zsx/workspace:/workspace --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" --gpus all --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" your_images /bin/bash`
```

**Note:**
In the command DISPLAY= XX, XX should be the value you get from `echo $DISPLAY`. Then you can run GUI program in the container.

**However**, I have encountered another problem. If the DISPLAY port changes, the program with GUI cannot run. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as suggested by @love7 but just replaced `-e DISPLAY=:15.0` with `-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY` and it worked for me.